Unable to Navigate to Vue Component Definition Using Vite Alias in Import Statement
If I click on the Component in
import Component from '@/components/Component.vue';

and try to go to the definition, it won't work when we use vite alias.
Looking for a possible solution.

try to "click" on '@/components/Component.vue' instead

@JaromandaX doesn't work

Does for me, sorry about that

@JaromandaX did you add something to your IDE settings to make it work? Also, recently the Vue Official extension was broken, maybe the last version causes this issue?

I have the latest extensions

If you install vue with npm init Vite,you have to set alias for using @.
vite.config.js
import path from 'path';
export default defineConfig({
    plugins:[...],
    resolve:{
        '@': path.resolve(__dirname,'./src')
    },
})

and check tsconfig.json in case you choose TypeScript or you run Visual Studio Code.
tsconfig.js
   "paths":{
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ]
   }

For your reference,src can change any path in your envilonments.

I had a vite alias set already. I use javascript. If I add the 'paths' to jsconfig.json, nothing happens.

I added to write in case of running VS-code.
